# 1+ GET request returning error 403 to heroku python

Tags: python, heroku

I'm using an api in my script. When I run the script via my own terminal, I'm successfully able to make 3 calls to the endpoint. But when I run the same script on heroku bash, only the first call is success, other two return Error 403. Here's my code

```
results = []

    for level in levels:
            headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
            res = requests.get(url+level,headers=headers)
            if res.status_code==200:
                res = json.loads(str(res.content))
                print "success"
                #do something
            else:
                print "Error",str(res.status_code)
        return results
```

In my terminal the output is

```
  success
  success
  success
```

In heroku bash the output is

```
  success
  Error 403
  Error 403
```

I've also tried it without the User-Agent header but same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permissions error. My guess is that when you run this from your browser, the first page sets various cookies, which the second and third requests require.

A quick possible fix, *IF* that's the issue, is to use requests' Session() objects. This stores cookies and sends them back on subsequent requests, kinda like a normal browser would.

```
results = []
mySession = requests.Session()

for level in levels:
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    res = mySession.get(url+level,headers=headers)
    if res.status_code==200:
        res = json.loads(str(res.content))
        print "success"
        #do something
    else:
        print "Error",str(res.status_code)

return results
```

Comment: It was worth a shot. The next step is to take the results of the second request, save it to disk, and look at the error in a browser. Hopefully the webpage will tell you what's wrong.